# Shutdown splash screen freezes after trying to shut down (21.04)

Tags: dual-boot, shutdown, windows-10, 21.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, and just installed 21.04 on my laptop and set it up to dual boot with Windows 10. When I shut down, either through the GUI or the terminal, the splash screen shows up, disappears, then comes back, frozen, while the fan ramps to full speed. When checking shutdown logs right during shutdown, I see that it reaches "Reached target Power-Off." Right after that, the fans spin up to full speed stay that way. I've let it sit in that state for about 15 minutes and nothing changes. The only way I'm able to completely shut down the system is by holding down the power button. Windows does not have this same problem.

PC Specs:

i5-5200u

6GB DDR3

Intel HD  Graphics 5500

256GB SSD (2 partitions, half for Ubuntu, half for W10)

Comment: Are your OSes installed in UEFI mode? If not, all bets are off. If they are then you may need to change one or more settings in the firmware and, of course, update it to the latest version available..

Comment: Click shutdown, then hit the ESC key to view the shutdown activity. Look for anything in RED. Note what the last few lines show. Take a picture. Also, show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: @heynnema I booted into recovery mode, and did a shutdown through the root terminal and i saw nothing red. The last line is the same as my original post. The result of that sudo command is "A08" and it is a Dell Inspiron 7548 and it has a "0AM6N0" motherboard according to hardinfo.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Dell Inspiron 7548

Your BIOS is current at version A08.

Turn off `Secure Boot` in your BIOS.

**In Ubuntu**

Let's check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**In Windows**

Let's disable `Fast Startup` and `Hibernation` in Windows...

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Comment: That did not work. Secure boot was already off. The results of the fsck showed '223013/7815168 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 3739517/31257344 blocks' and after following the steps on Windows, booting back into Ubuntu, and attempting to shut off again, the problem was still there.

Comment: @c1hucktay4lors Try this. Boot into your BIOS. Review your current BIOS settings, as you may need to set some items back after the next step. Find the choice "reset to factory defaults" or "reset BIOS" and choose it, then try booting Ubuntu and shutting down.

Comment: The only thing in my BIOS that is similar to the two choices is "restore defaults." I selected that. Booted into Ubuntu, tried to power down, and the problem remained. I also reinstalled Ubuntu by itself on the drive and the problem persisted. Both if the OS installs are brand new so I'm not losing any important data.

Comment: @c1hucktay4lors Last try... let's reset the Power Manager... unplug the computer from AC power, remove the battery (if possible), then hold down the power button for ~20 seconds. Retest.

Comment: That also unfortunately did not work. Same situation as before.

Comment: @c1hucktay4lors I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Not a problem. Really appreciate the help. I'll keep trying Ubuntu on virtuals to get a better understanding of it and try again at a later time. Thanks!